# How to display version of bootstrap that my site is running?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

During development, I like to show at the start of my application, the version of the libraries being used, on the js console. How can I do this for twitter bootstrap? I have taken a look at the `bootstrap.min.js` and see no reference at all to the version.

Comment: Inspecting minified file rarely helps. [Non-minified](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js) source contains version number, but only in a comment, so you have to parse it to get that info.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Small rant: I think the library should provide a way of directly accessing the version info (without extra parsing), at least the non-minified version.

Comment: Agree, but imo bootstrap.js is not a library, but a collection of jQuery plugins primary intended for UI prototyping.

Comment: Well, it has also a `.js` file, hasn't it? :) Anyway, bootstrap version **is** important: packages depend on specific bootstrap version. So it should be easily accessible. Actually, it would be great if there was a standardized mechanism to access the version for *any* library. Dreaming is free :)

Comment: +1 for embedded version tags in code in general that don't get dropped after minification.